# Dimming LED based on 12 V signal

Tags: led, dimming, tachometer

I've got an LM358 comparator turning on an LED. What I'd like to add is a way to dim the LED by a fixed amound when a 12 V signal is sensed.

It's in a tach circuit in a car, and when the headlights are turned on the dash lights get fed power, so when that occurs it's probably dark enough where the LED should be less bright.

I've got something modeled in LTspice with a resistor and NPN in parallel with the LED to draw off some of the current. Does that seem sensible or is there maybe a better way?

[image]

Here's an example of a similar 2-stage shift light in action:

[image: This is an example of a similar 2-stage shift light]

Comment: It sounds sensible but if you posted your schematic it might not be.

Comment: Yes, we need to see a schematic.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've got the schematic added now. This is.a really nice forum format for this type of thing!

Comment: Why 2 comparators doing same thing? Did you test this yet for RPM error, slew rate and ripple? Tachs are not usually rated like 725 Ohms rather in kRPM/V

Comment: Good questions Tony - this is an odd one.

The car is from 1968 and the tach is a Faria current sensing tach based on his 1958 patent US3005155, which uses a 1 mA full scale taut band meter movement. My DMM showed 725 ohms across the movement, and the current from the ohmmeter drove it to a 1500 rpm reading. So that's why I have the LM2917 set up as a freq to current converter.

Comment: The rest of the circuit is to make a 2-stage shift light. It takes the 7.3V zener ref voltage from the LM2917 and uses two different zeners that are 0.3 V apart to set two fixed setpoints. The voltage at pin 3 is proportional to RPM, and that gets multiplied based on the setpoint pot associated with U5, and then passed through the U2 area with no gain as the switch is closed during normal operation. Then the signal gets compared to each of the fixed setpoints and if higher the corresponding LED turns on. The 0.3V difference equates to approx. 500 rpm.

Comment: Ok I would think 0.1% R ratios might be more accurate than 5% Zeners to subtract from Vref. Ok if tach is 1mA full scale at say ?6000RPM then your R meter is sourcing 0.25mA to read some voltage converted to 725 ohms from 181mV  with some error tolerance so the tach could be same as ?6000 RPM/(4*181mV) or 120 RPM/mV. The only reason I mention this is an emitter follower output voltage is normally used should give a faster needle response.  Also isn’t Headlight Voltage isolated from Vbat ?

Comment: Good points Tony. I don't know why I was thinking a zener was what I needed. I guess at one point I planned to have the setpoint reference voltage get adjusted and a pair of zeners was an idea I had on how to keep the two at a fixed difference in voltage regardless. But I gave up on that so the zeners need to go in favor of voltage dividers.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with what you're doing wrong. Sorry.

Your use of zener diodes (D6) is backwards on two counts. First, any variation in the  7.3 volt level will cause the same change in the set point voltage. You should swap the diode and its resistor, which may require changing the diode part numbers.

51k for your zener resistors is far too high. Generally you want several mA of current through a zener to get stable voltage. A much better starting point would be 1k. This will obviously increase the current draw through R5 (470 ohms) and drop the 7.3 level. You may need to buffer the 7.3 with another LM358.

Assuming you're willing to live with battery voltage stability, can replace your zener/resistor pairs with simple resistor pairs, making voltage dividers to get the set points you need, with a capacitor across the lower resistor to ground just to keep things clean. You can use much higher resistances that way and avoid messing with a buffer for your 7.3.

As drawn, increasing the tach output will first turn on the green LED, and then the red, but the green will not turn off when the red turns on. That's pretty easy to fix, though.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwcW69.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your hysteresis resistors, R11 and R13 seem to have a reasonable ratio wrt the source resistors, but I'd be careful using 10 Meg resistors. It's easy to get in trouble with parasitic current paths, including solder flux. I'd be a lot happier seeing 20k/1M values, and 2k/100k even better.

With that said, your dimming approach looks reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, but I sold the car 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be difficult to make your scheme work properly. Essentially, you are trying to use an NPN transistor to connect a resistor in parallel with an LED, hoping that the resistor will draw some large fraction of the current that would have gone through the LED. The problem I see is that the voltage across the resistor is proportional to the current passing through it while the voltage across the LED is (relatively) constant. So, the degree of current sharing between the LED and the resistor will change significantly as the supply voltage changes. What you have indicated as your "+12V" supply will actually vary quite a bit as the engine RPM changes, the A/C cycles on and off, and the battery charge level changes...it's probably over 14V when the battery is charging with few other loads. At low RPM the LED may not work at all.

To make the circuit more reliable you should probably add a voltage regulator for the LM358 comparators, so the LED circuits will see a more constant voltage. To change the brightness of the LEDs you should try to control the current through them. You need a way to add resistance in **series** with the LED when your headlights are on.

Comment: I can add a regulator. Without it the led current drops from 14mA to 9mA as battery voltage drops from 13.8v to 10v.

Comment: But I can't figure out how to add switched resistance in series. Can a digipot do that?

Comment: I would put a resistor in series with the LED (between the resistor and ground) and short across it with an NPN when the headlights are **not** on. Use another NPN with its base driven by the headlights...add a pullup on the collector, and use the collector voltage as your signal that the headlights are not on.

Comment: That's perfect. I used three NPNs, one with the pullup resistor, and then one at each of the LEDs. I did have to add diodes in each signal line to the second NPNs as without them there was a short bit of higher current thorough the LEDs when they first turned on. But it works very nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent circuit of your schematic when headlights are on is a 2.73V source in series with a 77ohm resistor. The low equivalent voltage, very close to LED voltage might lead to high variations  in LED current.

You can use an additional resistor in series with R15 (R23) shorted by a   MOSFET P-channel when headlights are off like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW2w2V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use an appropriate MOSFET with Vgs max > +-15v, Vds > 15V, Id > 100mA

A low gate voltage will open M1 shorting the adittional resistor.

This way the dependence of the power supply voltage is reduced, both headlights on or off having a 12V source.

Comment: Darn I just saw this answer and had already ordered parts. If the NPN arrangement doesn't work out though I'll try this next.

Comment: @mojozoom I'm sorry I was that late with the answer. I'm glad tough I was so fast to point the huge error in the first posted answer so no harm was done.

Comment: @mojozoom My doubts were if you can interrupt the circuit to insert an additional resistor but since there is no better answer I posted this anyway.

Comment: Well I spent quite a bit of time working with he LM2917-14 and was never able to get a linear current response from it with respect to the input frequency. I expect it's something I was doing wrong, but I've found that the available spice models really aren't 100% correct in their behavior, and as I'm not an electronics expert by any means I really rely on LTSpice.

Comment: The 555 circuit was doing a fine job providing a 12V square wave at 20% duty cycle as required, until I pulled my normal shenanigans and hooked it up backwards. I can only think of one circuit I've built that I haven't hooked up backwards. I even hooked my hot tub up backwards once (240 VAC!). Anyway, I've ordered some new 555's and some P-type mosfets to protect the poor little chips from me.

Comment: So I'm thinking of switching this project to Arduino. The 12V square wave is easy to generate, though I have to fudge it a little bit to get correct frequency output.